# Does ExpressionLanguage (EL) allow to call a method with a NULL argument?

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf-2, null, el

I use Tomcat7 with JSF2. I use method invocations like

```
 action="#{bean.method(22)}"
```

or

```
 action="#{bean.method(var)}"
```

where `var` is an EL variable.

However, if `var` is `null`, or i try to call `#{bean.method(null)` i get an NPE and the method is not called.

Is there any way to pass a `null` argument to a method in EL?
Is there a literal for `null` in EL?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I can reproduce this issue on Tomcat 7.0.22, but not on Glassfish 3.1.1. The NPE stacktrace hints that the Apache EL implementation is wrong here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
    at org.apache.el.util.ReflectionUtil.isAssignableFrom(ReflectionUtil.java:299)
    at org.apache.el.util.ReflectionUtil.getMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:172)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:251)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
```

It shouldn't have called [`Class#isAssinableFrom()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) with a `null` argument. Its [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) also forbids that. I'd report it as a bug to the Tomcat guys over there at apache.org. Depending on what the [EL 2.2 spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/index.html) says, it should either been allowed (and thus the `Class#isAssignableFrom()` call should have been skipped), or been thrown as an [`ELException`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ELException.html) or one of its subclasses.

Comment: It would be nice if you post the issue URL here.

Comment: @jFrenetic: I didn't post it yet. It was just a suggestion to the OP. If the OP won't post it, I will maybe do it once I've read the EL spec once again even though this one is IMO clearly a bug. I've after several Tomcat bug reports experienced the Tomcat developers being extremely strict with regard to what the specs say.

Answer (score 0):

If possible (you have access to the bean method), you could change your method from int to Integer and then do a check for null before setting it.

```
method(int myInteger){
    if(myInt == null){
        return;
    }

    this.beanInt = myInteger;
}
```

Comment: That won't help, because the Exception is thrown before the bean method is called. (Changing to `Object` wonth help either.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Apache `7.0.47`. It disappeared after a update to `7.0.56`.

So it probably was a bug, although I couldn't find any issue tracker entry.